# How to get phone number from an incoming call from Android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I need to get **phonenumber** from **incoming call** it works well below Android 12 device with this method

```kotlin
val number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
```

but for *Android 12* and above device `(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` data is not available in intent.

Manifest permission is not issue I can add any permission if required. I've added this permission in my manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

I've also tried `contentResolver` query but it gives second last number data in cursor not current incoming call data.

```kotlin
val cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = ?",
    arrayOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE.toString()),
    CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC",
    cancellationSignal
)
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    val indexNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)
    val number = cursor.getString(indexNumber)
    print(number)
    cancellationSignal.cancel()
    cursor.close()
}
```

Does anyone know How to find number for Android 12 and above device?

Comment: You can use call screening api from google https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService

Comment: I've implemented `onScreenCall` for `CallScreeningService()` and tried to parse data from `Call.Details` but it shows null and empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in Call.Details

```
 private fun extractPhoneNumber(callDetails: Call.Details): String? {
    val handle = callDetails.handle
    if (handle != null) {
        // Attempt to extract phone number from the handle
        return handle.schemeSpecificPart
    } else {
        // Handle is null, try other methods if available
        val gatewayInfo = callDetails.gatewayInfo
        if (gatewayInfo != null) {
            return gatewayInfo.originalAddress.schemeSpecificPart
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me from Android 12 device

Comment: But I'm not getting name from `callerDisplayName` property of  `callDetails` . Does anyone have extract name from CallDetails?